# Comparing the means of latent variables in a CFA model measured at two different times in R

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, manova, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I have a CFA model with 7 latent variables and about 4 items per construct, I'm using R with lavaan for the CFA, $N\approx 3500$.

My model looks like this:

```
L1 =~ L1_a + L1_b + L1_c + L1_d
L2 =~ L2_a + L2_b + L2_c + L2_d
...
L7 =~ L7_a + L7_b + L7_c + L7_d
```

Here L1 stands for "Latent variable 1" and `_a,_b,_c,_d` indicates four items measuring the same latent variable.

However, the items are from a questionnaire that has been administered at $T_0$ and at $T_1$, i.e. at two points in time.

To help visualize my data structure:

```
L1_a L1_b L1_c L1_d ... L3_a L3_b L3_c L3_d ... Time
  1    2    5    3        1    1    4    5        0
  1    1    3    4        2    2    3    1        1
```

This is Likert-scale data that is non-normally distributed.

My problem: I want to compare the mean of L1 at $T_0$ with the mean of L1 at $T_0$ (and the same for L2-L7). I.e. I want to see whether there is a statistically significant change in the means of the latent variables from $T_0$ to $T_1$.

I've spent the day googling this but I've ended up very confused.

My question: What is the right approach to take?

Comment: What have you tried? If you've spent the day Googling it, it seems that someone is going to reiterate what you've already found. Can you explain the problem?

Comment: @JeremyMiles I have tried to find methods that fit my problem. I have looked at MANOVA, growth curve modeling, group comparison, multilevel models and mixed-models. My confusion is conceptual, hence 'what is the right approach for what I'm trying to achieve re. means comparisons'

Comment: You want to focus your search on longitudinal measurement invariance. E.g., https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5121102/ for categorical items. It is easier with continuous items. Also see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/semTools/versions/0.4-14/topics/longInvariance

Comment: Ah, OK, I see. First you need to make your data wide (or wider). A person should only be on one row. So you should have variables L1_a_t1, L1_b_t1 .... L7_d_t7. (If I've understood correctly).

Comment: Then you need to be concerned about longitudinal invariance.

Comment: You've got a very large and complex model here. Do you want to model all four latents in one big model? Or can you split it into four (fairly large, fairly complex) models?